# Read data from JSON Url using plain javascript and display it in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, json-api

I need to read data from json generated url using plain javascript and display the data in html.i have searched alot but i couldn't find exactly what i need. Can you please give me some startup like what should i do to or any reference materials. I really want to learn and implement it on my own.

P.S: I am a beginner in JavaScript.

Comment: To clarify, you would like to fetch data from a URL (endpoint). The data you are trying to fetch is in JSON format? You then want to do something with this data (parse it) and output it to your HTML (DOM)?

Comment: Be aware of CORS, most websites won't allow you to load their content directly from your browser, it's worth understanding CORS before you get started with this particular thing, you'll save a lot of headaches

Comment: @Alex Mulchinock Yes!That's Right. I know how to generate json url or api. But i don't know how to get json data using javascript and display the data in HTML.

Comment: @AnkitaRoy jQuery has a function (method) that would allow you to do this very easily. If you're looking to only use vanilla Javascript, then Pranav's answer below might be a good place to start.
Let me know if you would like to see an example with jQuery. Pravav already has you covered otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ES6 fetch API to load the request data and then render it.

```
fetch('http://example.com/movies.json')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(myJson) {
    console.log(myJson);
  });
```

Here's a tutorial on fetch API: https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-use-the-javascript-fetch-api-to-get-data

Fetch is now supported in all modern browsers: https://caniuse.com/#feat=fetch